# pg_class OID exhaustion by frequently creating temporary tables

Tags: postgresql

Does PostgreSQL have mechanism of dealing with rapidly growing `OID` counter on pg_catalog.pg_class table especially when that counter ticks over the maximum number of unique integer values.

I have a very busy database with many concurrent processes that rely on frequently creating temporary tables via `CREATE TEMP TABLE ... ON COMMIT DROP`. Most of transactions are very short and temp tables are automatically dropped at the end but the counter on `pg_catalog.pg_class.oid` is rapidly moving forward.

What is going to happen when that counter makes a complete "circle around the integer"? Will it intelligently avoid collisions and if so will it come at a cost of performance or other negative side effects?

I perused PostgreSQL documentation and found information about `OID` transaction wraparound but no references to what happens when `pg_catalog` tables exhaust all IODs.

Comment: I have hardly ever used temporary tables, let alone creating them hundreds of times per second. What are you doing that it requires that many temporary tables? I would be very surprised if that is really necessary.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't necessary to create it this way but it is beyond the scope of this question. There is a product that behaves this way and I have to deal with it :)

Answer (score 1):

OID wraparound is not your worry. PostgreSQL will avoid collisions when assigning and OID to a table.

You problem may be table bloat. Whenever a temporary table is created and removed, this causes dead tuples in the `pg_attributes` tables. So you should make sure that that catalog table is vacuumed aggressively (low `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay`) so that it doesn't bloat.